# Strange viewer behaviour with overwritten files

Tags: autodesk-forge

Recently i experienced a strange viewer behaviour: uploading a Revit file on the same bucket and with the same file name (i.e. ovewriting the file), selecting an object the property panel showed propreties from objects different from the selected one. Maybe overwriting files shuffles the dbIds assigning dbIds to different objects in different file versions?

Comment: Have you seen this article already? I'm wondering if some parts of the model (either viewables or properties) are coming from the cache and cause the inconsistency.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-keeps-showing-old-model

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, actually i found that there was a cache problem, too. Deleting data from the cache in the browser eventually worked. But what i would like to do is updating files in the bucket as i normally do in BIM360, i mean i would like to keep tha same reference, same urn, but perodically upload new versions with some changes. I can't seem to be able to do so. Any suggestion on further readings or...? many thanks!

Comment: "as i normally do in BIM360" in that case each file version is stored with a different name in the underlying OSS bucket. You as well could do the same - just e.g. attach version number (like "[v3]") to each file name
If you do not want to change the file name for each version, then making sure that nothing is cached when viewing the file (as pointed out in the blog posts) should do the trick

Comment: As usual, thank you very much for your kindness and quick response